# uWSGI Python exception handling

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have a python wsgi app which is run with uwsgi (and nginx). The problem is when there's an exception raised by my app, uwsgi just prints it but nothing else happens. For example, there are settings in my app, that are read from a file, and I need the uwsgi service to not be able to start if the file wasn't found.

I could catch those exceptions and log warnings, but I feel this is not enough to ensure that the app was properly initialized with all the settings found etc.

What is the proper way to handle these cases?

Edit:
I don't need to terminate a single worker process, I want either exit the whole uwsgi service, or handle it in some other and hopefully more graceful way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exit uWsgi worker (python werkzeug) from internal error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235725/how-can-i-exit-uwsgi-worker-python-werkzeug-from-internal-error)

Comment: No, it is not. I have one configuration that is loaded before any requests to the app are made.